# Form field per table row in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a settings table in my Rails app that has the following columns:

`id, name, value`

An example of some sample data might be:

```
id: 1,
name: 'site_name'
value: 'Cameron'

id: 2
name: 'email'
value: 'cameron@example.com'
```

What I want to do is have a page where I list these settings as simple text fields that I can then edit and save back into the database.

I have the following controller method that lists them:

```
def index
    @settings = Setting.all
end
```

And then display them in the view like so:

```
<% @settings.each do |setting| %>
<div class="form__group">
  <label class="form__group__label"><%= setting.name %></label>
  <div class="form__group__input">
    <input type="text" name="setting[<%= setting.name %>]" value="<%= setting.value %>">
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Which displays them fine. But how do I save them?

I was thinking about looping through them in the controller like:

```
def update_settings
  params[:setting].each do |setting|
      # somehow update each param sent back...
  end
end
```

Comment: Do it in a edit way (edit.html page) spite of a index form.  in the edit method of your controller call @settings = Setting.all. List in the same way into de edit.html including all the row into the form. edit and apply summit normaly. Implement yout update method in your controller, receive de params and persist all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update action should look like

```
def update_settings
  params[:setting].each do |setting|
    setting_row = Setting.where(name: setting.first).first_or_initialize
    setting_row.update(value: seting.last)
  end
end
```

I'm using .first_or_initialize method for possible use case when Setting with that name does not exist.

Comment: That looks cool. Although I'm getting the error: `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` on this line: `setting_row = Setting.where(name: setting[:name]).first_or_initialize`

Comment: Please show me your params[:setting] in update action and I will help you.

Comment: `setting: ["site_name", "Cameron"]`

Comment: params[:setting].each do |setting|
    setting_row = Setting.where(name: setting.first).first_or_initialize
    setting_row.update(seting.last)
  end

Comment: Doing that causes the error: `When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.` on the update line.